# Using jQuery, how do I get a specific dropdown element (<select></select>) based on the value of the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors, dropdown

I have a class of dropdowns -- .selMapField -- and I want to select the dropdown that has a specific value. For instance:

```
const myattr=$(`.selMapField[value="MYSKU"]`).attr(`x`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to find the elements by value

```js
const myattr = $(".selMapField").filter((_, { value }) =>
  value === "MYSKU").attr("x")
  
console.log(myattr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<select class="selMapField" x="A"><option selected>FOO</option></select>
<select class="selMapField" x="B"><option selected>MYSKU</option></select>
<select class="selMapField" x="C"><option selected>BAR</option></select>
```

---

As always, [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```js
const myattr = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(".selMapField")
).find(({ value }) => value === "MYSKU")?.getAttribute("x")
  
console.log(myattr)
```

```html
<select class="selMapField" x="A"><option selected>FOO</option></select>
<select class="selMapField" x="B"><option selected>MYSKU</option></select>
<select class="selMapField" x="C"><option selected>BAR</option></select>
```

Comment: in the javascript example, what is the function of the "?" in "?.getAttribute("x")" ? ESLint 9 flags it as an issue but it works perfectly well.

Comment: Oh...it's optional chaining...how cool.

Comment: That's correct. I'm curious, what is the eslint warning?

Comment: Expected an identifier and instead saw '.'. (E030)jshint(E030)

Comment: I think your linter is out of date ~ https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/3448